# Cannot tap-to-focus using react-native-vision-camera and react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: react-native, focus, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-vision-camera

I am implementing a camera on my react native app using the [React Native Vision Camera](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera) library and tap gesture from react native gesture handler but cannot seem to get it work. It sometimes goes blur where i tap and at other times does nothing at all. I am able to log the x and y coordinates but the camera does not focus on the tapped point.[Guide to focus](https://react-native-vision-camera.com/docs/guides/focusing)

Would appreciate any help with this. Thanks :)

Here is the part of the camera component dealing with the tap to focus functionality.

```
const handleFocusOnTap = async(tapEvent) => {
        try {
            if (cameraDevice.supportsFocus && cameraRef && tapEvent && tapEvent.x !== undefined && tapEvent.y !== undefined) {
                
                await cameraRef?.current?.focus({
                        x: tapEvent.x,
                        y: tapEvent.y
                });
                console.log(tapEvent.x, tapEvent.y)    
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);            
        }
    };

    const tap = Gesture.Tap().onEnd((event, success) => {
        const focusAsync = async() => {
            await handleFocusOnTap(event);
        };
        if (success) {          
            focusAsync();
        } else {
            console.error()
        }
    });

    return (
        <>
            <StatusBar style="light"/>
            <AfterInteractions>
                <View style={cameraScreenStyles.cameraContainer}>
                    <GestureDetector gesture={tap} >
                        <Camera
                            style={cameraScreenStyles.camera}
                            ref={cameraRef}
                            device={cameraDevice}
                            isActive={true}
                            photo={true}
                            enableZoomGesture={true}
                            enableHighQualityPhotos={true}
                            orientation={orientation}
                            focusable={true}
                        />
                    </GestureDetector>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Native Vision Camera has now released an example of focusing using React Native Gesture Handler and it works great! :)

```
import { Camera, useCameraDevice } from 'react-native-vision-camera'
import { Gesture, GestureDetector } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

export function App() {
  const camera = useRef<Camera>(null)
  const device = useCameraDevice('back')

  const focus = useCallback((point: Point) => {
    const c = camera.current
    if (c == null) return
    c.focus()
  }, [])

  const gesture = Gesture.Tap()
    .onEnd(({ x, y }) => {
      runOnJS(focus)({ x, y })
    })

  if (device == null) return <NoCameraDeviceError />
  return (
    <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
      <Camera
        ref={camera}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
        device={device}
        isActive={true}
      />
    </GestureDetector>
  )
}
```